# Javascript Validate Sum of array elements net to zero

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, parsefloat

I have a requirement to validate the sum of the elements of my array net to zero. The array could contain positive or negative values.
The array elements are 1164.44,-2919.42,2500.59,-5197.15,4451.54
My code without using toFixed is

```
    var v_total=0;
   var v;
   var varray  = document.getElementsByName('f02');
   for (var i = 0; i < varray.length; i++)
   {

      v = (isNaN(parseFloat(varray[i].value)))?0:varray[i].value;
     v_total = parseFloat(cv_total) + parseFloat(v);

   }

    v_total = (isNaN(cv_total))?0:cv_total;
```

which results with the sum 9.094947017729282e-13
If I add it using a calc, it does net to zero
Searched the forum and understand that it is the behaviour of floating numbers.
Despite using toFixed, I am unable to get the sum zero . Also the number of digits after the decimal could vary and is not always 2
Request any advice on how to workaround this

Thanks

Comment: You could do a Math.ceil/floor/round and test that the result is < .1 from the raw result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce() and toPrecision():

```js
    var arr =[1164.44,-2919.4204,2500.5904,-5197.151,4451.541]; 
    var result = arr.reduce(function(a, b){ return +a.toPrecision(15) + +b.toPrecision(15) });
    alert(result);
```

Comment: Thank you Johann for your suggestions and also for introducing me to reduce function ...I implemented your solution

Comment: @RJD I'm glad I could help. You accepted another answer, but an upvote doesn't hurt :)

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, what seems to be the problem?

```
var n=[1164.44,-2919.42,2500.59,-5197.15,4451.54];
s=n.reduce(function(x,y) {
    return parseFloat((x+y).toFixed(2));
});
console.log(s);
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/91g4qb0z/

Comment: Yes. Instead parseFloat you can also use the plus prefix:
`var arr =[1164.44,-2919.42,2500.59,-5197.15,4451.54];
arr.reduce(function(a, b){  return +a.toFixed(2) +  +b.toFixed(2)  })`

Comment: The vlaues are entered in a text which is an array and it is editable.when I enter whole numbers or large negative numbers instead of adding, I got the concatenation of the elements despite using parseFloat . v_total += parseFloat(varray[i].value).toFixed(2);
     console.log(v_total);

Comment: Thank you Johann , preceding with the + sign did the trick . Now the numbers do add up, however I cant always be certain there are 2 digits after the decimal . For Eg 5.468 , -5.47 do not net to zero, how do I aprroach the toFixed if my digits after decimal vary ?

Comment: @RJD Use Number.prototype.toPrecision() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision with the precision you like. 

`[5.468, -5.47].reduce(function(a, b){ return +a.toPrecision(15) + +b.toPrecision(15) })`

You must set a precision (like 15 here) and validate that the numbers added by the user doesn't be larger than your parameter (15 in this case).

Comment: @RJD I added an answer with Number.prototype.toPrecision()

Answer (score 0):

**Using Multiple Pointer Approach**

**Time Complexity:** O(n)

**Space Complexity:** O(1)

```
const sumZero = (arr) => {
    let left = 0;
    let right = arr.length-1;
    
    while(left < right) {
        let sum = arr[left] + arr[right];
        if(sum === 0) return [arr[left], arr[right]];
        else if(sum > 0) right--;
        else left++;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(sumZero([1164.44,-2919.4204,2500.5904,-5197.151,4451.541]));
```